# Decimal format in countdown timer

Tags: jquery, countdown

I am using a jquery plugin http://rendro.github.io/countdown

I want to do a countdown with millisecond like 15 secs to 15.00 secs

Here is what I have tried. It didnt work.

```
$('.counter').countdown({
    date: +(new Date) + 15000,
    render: function(data) {
        var ti= this.leadingZeros(data.sec, 2);
        var ts= ti.toFixed(2);
        $(this.el).text(ts + " sec");
    }
});
```

Here is jsfiddle link http://jsfiddle.net/bojscctj/

Answer (score 0):

you can do this without using any plugin like:

**[FIDDEL](http://jsfiddle.net/y6BZV/)**

```
  var count = 3000;

    var counter = setInterval(timer, 10); //10 will  run it every 100th of a second

    function timer()
    {
        if (count <= 0)
        {
            clearInterval(counter);
            return;
         }
         count--;
         document.getElementById("timer").innerHTML=count /100+ " secs"; 
     }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this out

```
$('.counter').countdown({
date: +(new Date) + 15000,
render: function(data) {
var ti= this.leadingZeros(data.sec, 2) +"."+this.leadingZeros(data.millisec, 2);
$(this.el).text(ti + " sec");
}

});
```

JSFiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/gw91La5y/2/

Answer (score 0):

use `parseFloat` before `toFixed` method.

```
$(this.el).text(parseFloat(ti).toFixed(2) + " sec");
```

Complete code as follows

```
$('.counter').countdown({
    date: +(new Date) + 15000,
    render: function(data) {
    var ti= this.leadingZeros(data.sec, 2);
    $(this.el).text(parseFloat(ti).toFixed(2) + " sec");
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks Cap! I tried this before. Milliseconds wont tick. Only seconds tick. I just want user to have something like 9.5 secs.